# Javascript unicode regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, unicode

I want to convert all the numbers in a string to a symbol.

`Hell1o2` changed to `Hell1!o2”`

```
'Hell1o2'.replace(/[1-9]/g, '$&\u0021')
```

How do I change the last Unicode number to change the symbol?

1 = u0021

2 = u0022

For example, if something like this works, my problem will be solved

```
'Hell1o2'.replace(/[1-9]/g, `$&\u002${$&}`)
```

Comment: what do you get?

Comment: change `'\u0021$&'` to `'$&\u0021'` (insert $& first)

Comment: question updated.

Comment: Your question is missing details. If there will be a symbol for each number, where are the other 8 symbols? Another, will the symbols be associated with a specific symbol or will they be random symbols?

Comment: The string is not fixed. With each new number in the string, a new symbol is formed. My problem is just changing the last Unicode digit.

Comment: Yes dear friend I need it.